# How to deploy a module

Tags: esper

I have a problem with deploying module. Here is `module.epl`:

```
    import com.fss.demo.esperevent.*;

    @Name('Count-Switched-On')
    select count(*) from DemoSimpleEvent1;
```

and the code

```
{       
    DemoSimpleEvent1 demoSimpleEvent1 = new DemoSimpleEvent1();

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.addEventTypeAutoName("com.fss.demo.esperevent");
    EPServiceProvider EpService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(config);
    EPDeploymentAdmin deployAdmin = EpService.getEPAdministrator().getDeploymentAdmin();

    MyListener myListener = new MyListener();

    try {
        Module module = deployAdmin.read(new File("module.epl"));

        DeploymentResult MyResult = deployAdmin.deploy(module, new DeploymentOptions());            
        EPStatement Stta = EpService.getEPAdministrator().getStatement("Count-Switched-On");
    } catch (IOException | ParseException | DeploymentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

but `Stta` is `null`,and `MyResult.statement` does not contain any statement. 
So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks allright, maybe the code is reading the wrong file?
Perhaps pack it up into a complete test class and send it to the Esper user mailing list.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem.
The problem here is version of library antlr-runtime.jar
With esper 4.11.0.jar, should use antlr-runtime-3.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem.
The problem here is version of library antlr-runtime.jar
With esper 4.11.0.jar, should use antlr-runtime-3.2.jar